# How to write a script to stop and start glassfish server

Tags: bash

I am using glassfish server for my Application and this is the way i start and stop my glassfish server manually

```
 /opt/glassfish4/bin/asadmin stop-domain

 /opt/glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain
```

My requirement is that daily at 11:30 PM i want to restart my server automatically through a script

My question is that do i need to write two scripts ??

and mentuion it in two entries in cron tab ??

one for stopping

```
 /opt/glassfish4/bin/asadmin stop-domain
```

and

one for starting

```
 /opt/glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain
```

Is this the correct way or else please guide me whats the correct way of doing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd add the following entry to your crontab:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
30 23 * * * /opt/glassfish4/bin/asadmin stop-domain && /opt/glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create one script that first stop and then start it

myscript.sh

```
 /opt/glassfish4/bin/asadmin stop-domain
 /opt/glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain
```

and invoke it via crontab. You can refer to this [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) for using crontab